# Linux: How to display message when running command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Is it possible to make the command line display a message when running a command? I have used shell scripts to intercept command names and display messages and then launch the command, but I was wondering if something more "native".

Something like an if statement in the bashrc that says **if xyzcommand then echo message and run xyz command.**

As an example I'm thinking of something along the lines of user runs "xeyes" and a message appears that says "watching you". But NOT after the program has executed, it needs to display while program is running.

```
[user@computer bin]$ xeyes 
watching you
```

Comment: iTerm2 does something like this using "Shell integration", so you could search for that.

Comment: Rather than an if statement in the bashrc, you could just override it with a function: `xeyes() { echo watching you; command xeyes; }`

Answer (score 1):

you can run two commands at the same time, by running them in the background with & 
example: `your-script.sh & popup_message_programm &`

to display a message you can use in example Libnotify
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_notifications

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to William Pursell for the hint!

I set a function in the /etc/bashrc

```
function xeyes {
echo ""
echo "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
echo "!!!!! Watching You !!!!!"
echo "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
echo ""
/usr/bin/xeyes     
}
```

Very important part here! **DO NOT** just put the command name in the function if the function is meant to have the **SAME NAME**!

Otherwise what happens is that the bashrc function does the echo and then runs the command, but the bashrc then redirects the command name back to the function itself and echos the message again.....creating an endless loop. If you want to have the function be the same name as the command then you need to put the full path (or something referencing the full path) of the command in the function as seen above.

Now when I type xeyes, I get the message as well. But when I type "which xeyes" I still get the useful /usr/bin/xeyes message.